# Cannot Access Docker Phpmyadmin via Port

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, dockerfile

I set up a typical webenvironment on the Google Cloud Platform via Docker.

Nginx, Php, MySQL is up and running. Next thing I want is Phpmyadmin, but here I stumble upon a connectivity issue. 
I cannot reach phpmyadmin via myip:1234 as it is stated in the Documentation.

Here is the important part of my Docker-Compose.yml

```
  mysql:
    build: mysql-docker/.
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_USER: florian
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db


  phpmyadmin:
    build: phpmyadmin/.
    links:
     - mysql:db
    ports:
     - 1234:80
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
     PMA_USERNAME: florian
     PMA_PASSWORD: pw
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
    restart: always
```

This is my phpmyadmin Dockerfile

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
EXPOSE 80
```

Does anybody know what happens to me in that case? I searched a lot of topics and tried a lot but didn't find the solution.

Comment: I don't know google cloud platform but do you probably need to do some port forwarding? The docker compose file looks valid to me.

Comment: Absolutely Thanks @MathiasJ. I was searching in my Docker Setup for hours but the solution was that simple

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad to helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

As Matthias said, it was a Port needed on the GCP.
So it had nothing to do with Docker.

You do this like following:

1. Google Cloud Console
2. Network
3. Firewall Rules
4. Add New
5. Add tcp:1234